# sql delete query using multiple 'and' clause

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
DELETE  from Booking_Master
WHERE Req_No=@Req_No
AND LoginUser=@LoginUser
AND (Booking_Date!< convert(date, getdate()) 
AND (Booking_Date=convert(date, getdate()) 
AND Start_Time!<convert(time, getdate())))
```

Doing this query to delete records which is greater than current time. For example, it will deletes records like 2014-03-25 10:00:00.

What's wrong with the delete? Why am I deleting records with dates greater than the current time?

Comment: And your question is?

Comment: He just posted this so he can tell us that he made it! :)

Comment: Either that or he is threatening us.

Comment: Not working correctly it's also deletes records like `2014-03-25 10:00:00` this.

Comment: @Lifewithsun Which records do you want to delete?

Comment: which is greater than today's date and time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing what you want is this:

```
DELETE from Booking_Master 
WHERE Req_No=@Req_No 
AND LoginUser=@LoginUser 
AND 
(
 (Booking_Date > GETDATE()) 
 OR
 ( 
   Booking_Date = CONVERT(date, GETDATE()) 
   AND 
   Start_Time > CONVERT(time, GETDATE())
 )
)
```

It will delete records where Booking_Date is larger than getdate(), **or** Booking_Date is the same as getdate() and Start_Time is larger than getdate(). Note the use of parenthesis to ensure the correct evaluation of the logic as the AND operator has higher precedence than the OR operator..

Answer (score 0):

"!<" means [not less than](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189808.aspx). In other words it is greater than or equal to. You probably need only greater than ">"

So your query should probably be

```
DELETE  from Booking_Master
WHERE Req_No=@Req_No
AND LoginUser=@LoginUser
AND (Booking_Date > convert(date, getdate()) 
AND (Booking_Date=convert(date, getdate()) 
AND Start_Time > convert(time, getdate())))
```

Note the ">" in both `Booking_Date` and `Start_Time`

Hope this helps

Comment: When will Booking_Date be both larger than and equal to getdate()?